# For loop appending for each cycle at start rather than just once through its iteration

Tags: swift, for-loop

I am trying to get the key/values appended to some arrays once each. So my result should be a singular occurrence of each key/value pair in my array. However, after each iteration the key/value pair is added and then the iteration restart back at the beginning again, adding the key/value pair again each time.

How can  I make it only append each key/value pair once?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

var usernameScoreDict : [String:String] = ["erer":"eree", "veev":"veve", "tbtt":"bttbt", "umum":"muumu", "bvbv":"bbbcb"]

var unArray = [String]()
var hsArray = [String]()

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        usernameScoreDict.forEach { (key,value) in
            print("key is - \(key) and value is - \(value)")
            unArray.append(key)
            hsArray.append(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `let keys = Array(usernameScoreDict.keys)` and `let values = Array(usernameScoreDict.values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop like this:-

```
for (key, val) in usernameScoreDict{
    unArray.append(key)
    hsArray.append(value)
}
```

Afterwards you can remove repeated value if any(as I don't think so it will happen) by using set:-

```
unArray = (Array(Set(unArray)))
hsArray = (Array(Set(hsArray)))
```

Comment: A dictionary can not have repeated keys, it can only have repeated values.

Comment: I know that Sir @LeoDabus that why i stated the line - Afterwards you can remove repeated value if any(as I don't think so it will happen) by using set.

Comment: `unArray = (Array(Set(unArray)))` is pointless. Btw no need for those outer pharenteses

Comment: @PratyushPratik what he means is that `Set` is only useful when there is a chance for repeated values to occur. And the keys in a dictionary will **never** contain the same value more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create arrays of keys and values from the dictionary

```
let keysArray = [String](usernameScoreDict.keys)
let valuessArray = [String](usernameScoreDict.values)
```